# vba export emails from outlook to excel and automatically close excel and save changes

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Im sorry about the large amount of code but I've been looking over a number of days now to try and resolve this problem. Basically this code runs in outlook when I start it up. It exports different types of emails from different inbox's where different subject headers exist.

It collects parts of the subject heading and parts of the email body and exports this as text into my excel spreadsheet.

The problem I have is that this code actually works fine, and it use to open an excel spreadsheet in the background and export the information into a new row in the relevant columns. Once it has done this it would automatically save the spreadsheet and close.

Now however for some reason, it will do all of that but will not close the spreadsheet and Excel shows up as a running service in windows task manager. This should not be the case and the spreadsheet should save changes and close automatically.

```
'On the next line edit the path to the spreadsheet you want to export to
    Const WORKBOOK_PATH = "X:\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\Supplier SetUps & Amendments.xls"
    'On the next line edit the name of the sheet you want to export to
    Const SHEET_NAME = "Validations"
    Const SHEET_NAME2 = "BankSetup"
    Const SHEET_NAME3 = "CreditChecks"
    Const SHEET_NAME4 = "Statistics"
    Const MACRO_NAME = "Export Messages to Excel (Rev 7)"
    Const xlContinuous As Integer = 1
Const vbBlack As Integer = 0
Const xlThin As Integer = 2






        Dim olkMsg As Object, _
        olkMsg2 As Object, _
            excApp As Object, _
            excWkb As Object, _
            excWks As Object, _
            excWks2 As Object, _
             excWks3 As Object, _
            excWks4 As Object, _
            intRow As Integer, _
            intRow2 As Integer, _
            intRow3 As Integer, _
            intRow4 As Integer, _
            intExp As Integer, _
            intVersion As Integer
        intVersion = GetOutlookVersion()
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Open(WORKBOOK_PATH)
        Set excWks = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
        Set excWks2 = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME2)
        Set excWks3 = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME3)
        Set excWks4 = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME4)
        intRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        intRow2 = excWks2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        intRow3 = excWks3.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        intRow4 = excWks4.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
       'Write messages to spreadsheet
        Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim Items As Outlook.Items
        Dim Items2 As Outlook.Items
        Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
        Dim i As Long
        Dim lngCount As Long
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim strFolderpath As String
        Dim strDeletedFiles As String
        Dim withParts As String
        Dim withoutParts As String

        ' Get the MAPI Namespace
        Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ' Get the Items for the Inbox in the specified account
        Set Items = ns.Folders("New Suppliers").Folders("Inbox").Items
        Set Items2 = ns.Folders("Credit Checks").Folders("Inbox").Items
        ' Start looping through the items
        For Each olkMsg In Items
                'Only export messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
                If olkMsg.UnRead = True Then
                If olkMsg.class = olMail Then
                If olkMsg.Subject Like "Accept: (Update) New Supplier Request*" Or olkMsg.Subject Like "Accept: (Approval Required) - New Supplier Request*" Or olkMsg.Subject Like "Reject: (Approval Required) - New Supplier Request*" Or olkMsg.Subject Like "Accept: (IMPORTANT REMINDER!) - New Supplier Request*" Then
                        'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
                        Dim LResult As String
                        LResult = Replace(GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion), ".", " ")
                        LResult = Left(LResult, InStrRev(LResult, "@") - 1)
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = LResult
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = olkMsg.VotingResponse
                        Dim s As String
                        s = olkMsg.Subject
                        Dim indexOfName As Integer
                        indexOfName = InStr(1, s, "Reference: ")
                        Dim finalString As String
                        finalString = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfName - 10)
                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = finalString
                        intRow = intRow + 1
                        olkMsg.UnRead = False
                    End If
                End If


                If olkMsg.class = olMail Then
                If olkMsg.Subject Like "Complete: Bank Details Set-Up for New Supplier*" Or olkMsg.Subject Like "Incomplete: Bank Details Set-Up for New Supplier*" Then
                        'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
                        excWks2.Cells(intRow2, 1) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
                        Dim LResult2 As String
                        LResult2 = Replace(GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion), ".", " ")
                        LResult2 = Left(LResult2, InStrRev(LResult2, "@") - 1)
                        excWks2.Cells(intRow2, 2) = LResult2
                        excWks2.Cells(intRow2, 3) = olkMsg.VotingResponse
                        Dim s2 As String
                        s2 = olkMsg.Subject
                        Dim indexOfName2 As Integer
                        indexOfName2 = InStr(1, s2, "Reference: ")
                        Dim finalString2 As String
                        finalString2 = Right(s2, Len(s2) - indexOfName2 - 10)
                        excWks2.Cells(intRow2, 4) = finalString2
                        intRow2 = intRow2 + 1
                        olkMsg.UnRead = False
                    End If
                End If

                 If olkMsg.class = olMail Then
                If olkMsg.Subject Like "New Supplier Request - Reference:*" Then
                        'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export

   Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 Dim b4 As String
 Dim strNewFolderName As String

 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b4 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
        indexOfNameb = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company name: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
       indexOfNamec = InStr(UCase(b4), UCase("Company number: "))

    Dim finalStringb As String

        finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)

        LResult336 = Replace(finalStringb, "Company Name: ", "")

        Dim LResult21 As String
        Dim LResult211 As String
        Dim LResult2113 As String
        LResult21 = Trim(LResult336)
        LResult211 = Replace(LResult21, Chr(10), "")
        LResult2113 = Replace(LResult211, Chr(13), "")


        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 2) = Trim(LResult2113)


    FolderPath = "\\uksh000-file06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Trim(LResult2113)
    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) = False Then
    Dim strDir As String
    strDir = "\\uksh000-file06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Trim(LResult2113)
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strDir
    FileCopy "X:\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\audit.xls", "X:\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Trim(LResult2113) & "\audit.xls"
    Else
    MsgBox "Directory exists."
    End If

    Else

    End If
    End If





Dim b5 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b5 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb2 As Integer
        indexOfNameb2 = InStr(UCase(b5), UCase("Company Number: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec2 As Integer
       indexOfNamec2 = InStr(UCase(b5), UCase("VAT Number: "))

    Dim finalStringb2 As String

        finalStringb2 = Mid(b5, indexOfNameb2, indexOfNamec2 - indexOfNameb2)

        LResult3362 = Replace(finalStringb2, "Company Number: ", "")

        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 3) = LResult3362


End If


Dim b6 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b6 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb3 As Integer
        indexOfNameb3 = InStr(UCase(b6), UCase("VAT Number: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec3 As Integer
       indexOfNamec3 = InStr(UCase(b6), UCase("Contact Name: "))

    Dim finalStringb3 As String

        finalStringb3 = Mid(b6, indexOfNameb3, indexOfNamec3 - indexOfNameb3)

        LResult3363 = Replace(finalStringb3, "VAT Number: ", "")

        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 4) = LResult3363


End If


Dim l As String
excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 5) = Trim(excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 5))
l = excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 5).Address
excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 6).FormulaArray = "=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Up'!$A$1:$G$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Up'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT(" & l & ",5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),6)),""ZZZ"",INDEX('Up'!$A$1:$G$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Up'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT(" & l & ",5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),6))"


Dim b7 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b7 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb4 As Integer
        indexOfNameb4 = InStr(UCase(b7), UCase("Description of the provisional Supplier:"))


    Dim indexOfNamec4 As Integer
       indexOfNamec4 = InStr(UCase(b7), UCase("Current Status: "))

    Dim finalStringb4 As String
    Dim LResult3364 As String
    Dim LResult33644 As String
    Dim LResult336445 As String


        finalStringb4 = Mid(b7, indexOfNameb4, indexOfNamec4 - indexOfNameb4)

        LResult3364 = Replace(finalStringb4, "Description of the provisional Supplier:", "")
        LResult33644 = Replace(LResult3364, Chr(10), "")
        LResult336445 = Replace(LResult33644, Chr(13), "")

        Dim TrimString As String
        TrimString = Trim(LResult336445)
        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 5) = Trim(TrimString)





End If




Dim b77 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b77 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb47 As Integer
        indexOfNameb47 = InStr(UCase(b77), UCase("Contact Number: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec47 As Integer
       indexOfNamec47 = InStr(UCase(b77), UCase("Contact Email: "))

    Dim finalStringb47 As String
    Dim LResult33647 As String
    Dim LResult336447 As String
    Dim LResult3364457 As String


        finalStringb47 = Mid(b77, indexOfNameb47, indexOfNamec47 - indexOfNameb47)

        LResult33647 = Replace(finalStringb47, "Contact Number: ", "")
        LResult336447 = Replace(LResult33647, Chr(10), "")
        LResult3364457 = Replace(LResult336447, Chr(13), "")

        Dim TrimString7 As String
        TrimString7 = Trim(LResult3364457)
        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 11) = Trim(TrimString7)

End If


Dim b777 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b777 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb477 As Integer
        indexOfNameb477 = InStr(UCase(b777), UCase("Contact Email: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec477 As Integer
       indexOfNamec477 = InStr(UCase(b777), UCase("Case Reference: "))

    Dim finalStringb477 As String
    Dim LResult336477 As String
    Dim LResult3364477 As String
    Dim LResult33644577 As String


        finalStringb477 = Mid(b777, indexOfNameb477, indexOfNamec477 - indexOfNameb477)

        LResult336477 = Replace(finalStringb477, "Contact Email: ", "")
        LResult3364477 = Replace(LResult336477, Chr(10), "")
        LResult33644577 = Replace(LResult3364477, Chr(13), "")

        Dim TrimString77 As String
        TrimString77 = Trim(LResult33644577)
        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 12) = Trim(TrimString77)

End If


Dim b7777 As String
 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b7777 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfNameb4777 As Integer
        indexOfNameb4777 = InStr(UCase(b7777), UCase("Requested Payment Term: "))


    Dim indexOfNamec4777 As Integer
       indexOfNamec4777 = InStr(UCase(b7777), UCase("Description of the provisional Supplier: "))

    Dim finalStringb4777 As String
    Dim LResult3364777 As String
    Dim LResult33644777 As String
    Dim LResult336445777 As String


        finalStringb4777 = Mid(b7777, indexOfNameb4777, indexOfNamec4777 - indexOfNameb4777)

        LResult3364777 = Replace(finalStringb4777, "Requested Payment Term: ", "")
        LResult33644777 = Replace(LResult3364777, Chr(10), "")
        LResult336445777 = Replace(LResult33644777, Chr(13), "")

        Dim TrimString777 As String
        TrimString777 = Trim(LResult336445777)
excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 29) = TrimString777

End If


                        Dim s4 As String
                        s4 = olkMsg.Subject
                        Dim indexOfName4 As Integer
                        indexOfName4 = InStr(1, s4, "Reference: ")
                        Dim finalString4 As String
                        finalString4 = Right(s4, Len(s4) - indexOfName2 - 34)
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 7) = finalString4


                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 9) = "Pending"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 10).Formula = "=IF(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 25).Address & "=""Declined"",""Manager has Declined"",IF(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 25).Address & "<>""Yes"",IFERROR(CONCATENATE(""Manager has "" & INDEX(Validations!$C$1:$C$9958,MATCH(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 7).Address & ",Validations!$D$1:$D$9958,0))),IF((TODAY()-" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 13).Address & ")>=5,""Approval Is Overdue"",""Approval Is Pending"")),IFERROR(CONCATENATE(""Manager has "" & INDEX(Validations!$C$1:$C$9958,MATCH(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 7).Address & ",Validations!$D$1:$D$9958))),""Approval Overidden"")))"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 15) = "Pending"


                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 13) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
                        Dim LResult33 As String
                        LResult33 = Replace(GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion), ".", " ")
                        LResult33 = Left(LResult33, InStrRev(LResult33, "@") - 1)
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 17) = LResult33
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 18) = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 17).Address & ",'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"""")"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 19) = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$H$1:$H$10004,MATCH(" & excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 17).Address & ",'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"""")"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 20) = "Yes"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 23) = "Attach"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 24) = "Audit"












                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 25).Formula = "No"









                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 27) = "=Username()"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 28) = "Pending"

                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 31) = "V0000847"
                         excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 32) = "Action"
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 33) = 1
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 33).Interior.ColorIndex = 35

                        Dim LResult21234 As String
                        LResult21234 = GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion)

                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 34) = "=HYPERLINK(""\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Trim(LResult2113) & "\log.txt"",""Log"")"
                        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                        Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Trim(LResult2113) & "\log.txt", True)
                        a.WriteLine ("Log for Supplier: " & Trim(LResult2113) & " (Created: " & Date & ")")
                        a.WriteLine (Date & " - " & Time & " - Request received in NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk by " & LResult21234 & ", and added to New Supplier Database")
                        a.Close






                        Dim Rng As Object
                         Set Rng = excWks4.Range("B" & intRow4 & ":AH" & intRow4 & "")
                         With Rng.Borders
                         .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                         .Color = vbBlack
                         .Weight = xlThin

                         End With

                         excWks4.Range("B" & intRow4 & ":AH" & intRow4 & "").WrapText = False


                        intRow4 = intRow4 + 1
                        olkMsg.UnRead = False



                        If IsNumeric(LResult3362) Then
                        TempFilePath = "\\UKSH000-File06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
strbody = "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:16'>" & "Dear New Accounts, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><B>F.A.O: Beth Crowe </b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "This is an automated email sent to you from New Suppliers. This is a credit refrence request." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Please would you be able to perform a credit check on the following new supplier:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><br>" & "Company Name: " & "<b>" & Trim(LResult2113) & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Company Number: " & "<b>" & Trim(LResult3362) & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Case Reference Number (Purchasing Use Only): " & "<b>" & finalString4 & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><br>" & "In the event that you have any enquiries, please keep a note of the case reference number. For any questions please contact NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Kind Regards," & "</font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:18'><b>Hewden Supply Chain Department</b></font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><img src='cid:cover.jpg'" & "width='800' height='64'><br>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<img src='cid:subs.jpg'" & "width='274' height='51'>"
With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk"
        .To = "mark.o'brien@hewden.co.uk"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "(Credit Reference) New Supplier Credit Check - Reference: " & finalString4
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "cover.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "subs.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .HtmlBody = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With

    Else


Dim b9 As String

 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b9 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfName9 As Integer
        indexOfName9 = InStr(UCase(b9), UCase("Full Name of Tradesman: "))


    Dim indexOfNam9 As Integer
       indexOfNam9 = InStr(UCase(b9), UCase("D.O.B of Tradesman: "))

    Dim finalString9 As String

        finalString9 = Mid(b9, indexOfName9, indexOfNam9 - indexOfName9)

        LResult3369 = Replace(finalString9, "Full Name of Tradesman: ", "")
End If


Dim b10 As String

 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b10 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfName99 As Integer
        indexOfName99 = InStr(UCase(b10), UCase("D.O.B of Tradesman: "))


    Dim indexOfNam99 As Integer
       indexOfNam99 = InStr(UCase(b10), UCase("Address of Tradesman: "))

    Dim finalString99 As String

        finalString99 = Mid(b10, indexOfName99, indexOfNam99 - indexOfName99)

        LResult33699 = Replace(finalString99, "D.O.B of Tradesman: ", "")
End If


Dim b101 As String

 If TypeName(olkMsg) = "MailItem" Then
    b101 = olkMsg.Body

    Dim indexOfName991 As Integer
        indexOfName991 = InStr(UCase(b101), UCase("Address of Tradesman: "))


    Dim indexOfNam991 As Integer
       indexOfNam991 = InStr(UCase(b101), UCase("VAT Number: "))

    Dim finalString991 As String

        finalString991 = Mid(b101, indexOfName991, indexOfNam991 - indexOfName991)

        LResult336991 = Replace(finalString991, "Address of Tradesman: ", "")
End If



    TempFilePath = "\\UKSH000-File06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
strbody = "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:16'>" & "Dear New Accounts, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><B>F.A.O: Beth Crowe </b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "This is an automated email sent to you from New Suppliers. This is a credit refrence request." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Please would you be able to perform a credit check on the following new supplier:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><br>" & "Trading Name: " & "<b>" & Trim(LResult2113) & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Full Name of Tradesman: " & "<b>" & LResult3369 & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Tradesman Date of Birth: " & "<b>" & LResult33699 & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Tradesman Address: " & "<b>" & LResult336991 & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Case Reference Number (Purchasing Use Only): " & "<b>" & finalString4 & "</b>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><br>" & "In the event that you have any enquiries, please keep a note of the case reference number. For any questions please contact NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Kind Regards," & "</font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:18'><b>Hewden Supply Chain Department</b></font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><img src='cid:cover.jpg'" & "width='800' height='64'><br>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<img src='cid:subs.jpg'" & "width='274' height='51'>"
With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk"
        .To = "mark.o'brien@hewden.co.uk"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "(Credit Reference) New Supplier Credit Check - Reference: " & finalString4
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "cover.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "subs.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .HtmlBody = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With





    End If

    End If


    End If



    End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see save and close lines in your code. Try something like:

```
excWks4.Save
excWks4.Close
```

You may need to declare excWks4 like Workbook istead of Object.

```
Dim excWks4 as Workbook
```

Comment: thanks I tried this solution but it doesn't seem to do the trick im affraid